# Messed up with Unity & Compiz

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz

I was making some changes in CCSM and I activated "rotate cube" plugin which asked me for resolving some conflicts & disabled all of them but with 11.04 something related to Unity were also disabled. I tried to restore it to defaults and then it all got screwed up.

And now if I am using the new Unity login, I just end up with my desktop, stuff on desktop and a mouse cursor.

I am able to go to terminal (tty) `Ctrl + Alt + F1` but I am not sure what I need to do to fix it. I want the settings to be what they were on a fresh install.

Comment: doesn't alt-f2 work either?

By the way, i think you can log in from a live cd and delete the compiz folder from your home folder.

Comment: Alt-f2 depends on panel service, I believe so none of the shortcuts were working. Thanks, I have solved the issue by resetting both Compiz & Unity.

Comment: It does? it works for me even when unity has crashed and i have no panels around.
Anyway, the important part is that you solved it

Comment: yeah! may be shortcut listener is still running after crash, not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To restore Compiz to default settings, try typing this into the terminal you have open:

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
```

To reset Unity to it's default settings, type:

```
unity --reset
```

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Comment: Will this work in tty1? I can't open a terminal in tty8

Comment: Great! That did it. Can you please correct your command though? It should be `/apps/compiz-1`

Comment: @Lee jarratt you added an extra dash

Comment: Just edited it :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact problem.

What solved this for me was to re-run ccsm and re-enable the Ubuntu Unity Plugin (can be found under the "Desktop" category), telling it to disable every conflicting feature if prompted to.

Comment: how do I get to CCSM? I am ended up with just a desktop without any panels

Comment: can you open a terminal somehow? 
If yes - run "ccsm" from there, if not - try running it from Ctrl+Alt+F1, setting the DISPLAY variable to :0.0 or whatever your display is.

Comment: I was able to run CCSM with `ccsm --display :0 ` and enabled Unity plugin but panels didn't show even after a reboot. I have resolved the problem though.